# Continuous Lorentz Transformation for time-like and space-like points

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, causality, lorentz-symmetry

On the page 28 of the book "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" by Michael E. Peskin and Daniel V. Schroeder in the last paragraph it says:
"When $(x−y)^2<0$ we can perform a Lorentz transformation taking $(x−y)→−(x−y)$. *Note that if $(x−y)^2>0$ there is no continuous Lorentz transformation that takes $(x−y)→−(x−y)$*."

Is the fact that there is no ***continuous*** transformation due to the necessity of having to cross over the null surface of the light cone (see fig. 2.4 in the book) to get from say, $t$ to $–t$, and therefore the transformation cannot be continuous? If so, if this could be explained I would appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/276677/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what figure you mean :-).

Yes, a Lorentz transformation cannot cross the null surface. Otherwise one could convert time-like into space-like distances. And since $\mathrm ds^2$ is Lorentz invariant, it cannot flip its sign either.